# Libevent 2.0.22 project Compilation problems (OSX)

Tags: c, libevent

I want to compile the sample code above, but I get the following error.
What is the reason for it.
"OSX - / usr / local" under all the files installed

```
// libevent2 library
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <evhttp.h>
#include <event2/event.h>
#include <event2/http.h>
#include <event2/bufferevent.h>

void generic_handler(struct evhttp_request *req, void *arg) {
    struct evbuffer *buffer;
    buffer = evbuffer_new();

    if (buffer == NULL) {
        err(1, "failed to create response buffer");
    }

    evbuffer_add_printf(buffer, "Requested: %sn", evhttp_request_uri(req));
    evhttp_send_reply(req, HTTP_OK, "OK", buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct evhttp *httpd;
    event_init();
    httpd = evhttp_start("0.0.0.0", 8080);
    // Set a callback for requests to "/specific".
    // evhttp_set_cb(httpd, "/specific", another_handler, NULL);
    // Set a callback for all other requests.
    evhttp_set_gencb(httpd, generic_handler, NULL);
    // Not reached in this code as it is now.
    event_dispatch();
    evhttp_free(httpd);
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
/Users/batuhangoksu/Desktop/test.c:14:10: fatal error: 'evhttp.h' file not found
#include <evhttp.h>
                 ^
1 error generated.
```

Command:

```
gcc -o octopus /Users/batuhangoksu/Desktop/test.c -levent -lpthread
```

Answer (score 1):

First, please find the `path` of `evhttp.h` file.

Then, you could check if this `path` is in the `#include` files search path list by command

```
gcc -o octopus /Users/batuhangoksu/Desktop/test.c -levent -lpthread -v
```

The output is like this,

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.1.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

If the `path` is not in the search list, then add `-I /missed_include`(assume it is the `path`) to your command, like

gcc -o octopus /Users/batuhangoksu/Desktop/test.c -levent -lpthread -I /missed_include